# paypal/rest-api-sdk-php PHP simple example

Tags: php, rest, paypal

I try to integrate paypal in my webapp.

I want to use paypal/rest-api-sdk-php for PHP

I checked tons of examples, but all of them look so complex, i need just simplest integration.

I want a user to enter an amount in a form and click "pay". after this i will build/get redirect url, redirect user to paypal , paypal redirects me back and i validate if payment was success.
If possible, i would not use IPN, but just some way to validate after redirect back.

Is there some simple example that does this workflow with modern PHP sdk?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using hard word like "rest" or "rest-api" even you have to redirect user on PayPal site. Api are useful in case you want to do transaction without redirecting user on PayPal site.

One simple HTML form is provided by PayPal to achieve your requirement.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="seller@designerfotos.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="hat">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="123">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="15.00">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://yourdomain.com/return">
<input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="John">
<input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="Doe">
<input type="hidden" name="address1" value="9 Elm Street">
<input type="hidden" name="address2" value="Apt 5">
<input type="hidden" name="city" value="Berwyn">
<input type="hidden" name="state" value="PA">
<input type="hidden" name="zip" value="19312">
<input type="hidden" name="night_phone_a" value="610">
<input type="hidden" name="night_phone_b" value="555">
<input type="hidden" name="night_phone_c" value="1234">
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="jdoe@zyzzyu.com">
<input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif"
alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
</form>
```

Add your PayPal account email in the field of "business". Set amount entered by user in the field "amount" and set return url in the field "return".

If you need more help the [check url](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/)

Comment: in this case how can i validate a payment? after this payment i need to add paid amount to a user balance . I need confirmation . will IPN work for this?

Comment: Yes IPN as well work with it. Do add one more hidden filed "<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://yourdomain.com/ipn">" and set your IPN url.

Comment: Ok. I see. But i will still try to find other solution. This approach will not work on my local environment as IPN call needs real public http server . I need something that can work on loval environment too.
If i can not find then will have to use this

Comment: Sure, if you decide to use this solution then first test it on sandbox mode by changing form tag with "<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">"